# p-table keep first column fixed/freeze

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I am using primeng p-table and I want to freeze the first column from horizontal scrolling. The header, body and footer first columns does not scroll when the table is scrolled horizontally. How can I do that?

I am using  for *ngIf in header, body and footer. Follow code below. Ignore any syntax error, there are no syntax error in original code.

```
<tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <ng-container *ngIf="condition; else nextTh2">
      <th>{{col.label}}</th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #nextTh>
      <ng-container *ngIf="condition2; else nextTh3">
        <th>{{col.label}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
    .
    .
    .
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pFrozenColumn` directive, placed on `th` and `td` elements in the header and body templates for the table.
If you want to freeze and unfreeze the column dynamically, use the directive together with the input `[frozen]`.

Here's an example from the PrimeNG documentation, found [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table/scroll) (Look for "Frozen Columns" on the page):

```
<p-table [value]="customers" scrollDirection="both" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="400px" styleClass="mt-3">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:200px" pFrozenColumn>Name</th>
            <th style="width:100px">Id</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Country</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Date</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Company</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Status</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Activity</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Representative</th>
            <th style="width:200px" alignFrozen="right" pFrozenColumn [frozen]="balanceFrozen">Balance</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-customer>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px" pFrozenColumn>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td style="width:100px">{{customer.id}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.country.name}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.date}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.company}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.status}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.activity}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.representative.name}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px" alignFrozen="right"  pFrozenColumn [frozen]="balanceFrozen">{{formatCurrency(customer.balance)}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: I am using ng-container for *ngIf, pFrozenColumn is not working on it.

Comment: Can you post the code you're referring to?

Comment: You are using `ng-container` but you do have `<td>` and `<th>` elements inside of them. It doesn't affect the usage of `pFrozenColumn`, as long as you place the directive on the right elements.
@npatel